# Timzone incorrect for log files only?

Tags: centos, logging, timezone

I have a small server running centos 6.4 and it is working quite nicely for some time. One thing that still bugs me is that the time in my log files is different then the time the 'date' command displays.

For example:

```
date
Thu May  9 13:39:04 BST 2013
```

And when i login with ssh i get a log entry in secure log:

```
May  9 08:37:08 xxxx sshd[28612]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user root by
```

The time difference seem to be always 5 hours. Which makes me think it is something timezone related.

My hwclock

```
cat /etc/sysconfig/clock 
ZONE="Europe/London"
```

My localtime

```
ls -al /etc/localtime 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 33 Apr  2 15:13 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London
```

My hwclock output

```
hwclock
Thu 09 May 2013 01:41:40 PM BST  -0.938110 seconds
```

All time settings (i know of) are correct. I restarted the sshd service and cron service, but log files still have the wrong timezone.

It seem to happen on many log files like messages, secure, maillog. Only log files from simple programs like bfd, rkhunter and such have the correct time.

Has anybody got an idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Try restarting the syslog service.

Comment: Thumbs up! It works, thank you for your very quick reply. /etc/init.d/rsyslog restart did solve the problem.

Comment: That one was news to me. Dennis, if you could write it as an answer with information about why it happens I'd be very interested.

Comment: Syslog caches the time when it boots up. It requires a restart to resync the time after a drift or dst or zone change.

Answer (score 18):

As Dennis pointed out try to restart syslog service. On centos 7 I did

```
systemctl restart rsyslog
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution. You need to download package tzdata:

```
yum install tzdata
```

and then restart asterisk, it will make logs time correct.